# Eclipse gives "sh: line 3: `;/root/Documents/mp3Eclipse/Test_MP3/Test_MP3;exit'" when I try to run mpg123 there

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, mp3, executable

I created a new project and loaded the source code from the zipped file (mpg123-0.59r.zip) and I followed the steps in the following link:
http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_existing_code.htm

to load the source code in Eclipse. The executable has been created and when I press "Run", I get the standard output:

```
/root>
Hello World!!!
```

I want to run to be able to play an audio file from Eclipse.
This is what I have done so far:

In Eclipse, I clicked on "Run", went to "Run Configurations".
Under "C/C++ Remote Applications", I created a file "Test_MP3 Debug(1)".
For "Remote Absolute File Path for C/C++ Application", I gave the address for my executable.

Beneath this option, there is "Commands to execute before application". When I type some commands there like `mpg123 -t` I get the proper output. However, when I type a command for playing an audio file like `mpg123 -/root/Downloads/mpg123-0.59r/sample.mp3`I get the following output:

```
mpg123: Unknown option "/".
sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
sh: line 3: `;/root/Documents/mp3Eclipse/Test_MP3/Test_MP3;exit'
```

When I removed "/" before `root` , I got the following output:

```
/root>
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layer 1, 2 and 3.
Version 0.59r (1999/Jun/15). Written and copyrights by Michael Hipp.
Uses code from various people. See 'README' for more!
THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

usage: mpg123 [option(s)] [file(s) | URL(s) | -]
supported options [defaults in brackets]:
   -v    increase verbosity level       -q    quiet (don't print title)
   -t    testmode (no output)           -s    write to stdout
   -w <filename> write Output as WAV file
   -k n  skip first n frames [0]        -n n  decode only n frames [all]
   -c    check range violations         -y    DISABLE resync on errors
   -b n  output buffer: n Kbytes [0]    -f n  change scalefactor [32768]
   -r n  set/force samplerate [auto]    -g n  set audio hardware output gain
   -os,-ol,-oh  output to built-in speaker,line-out connector,headphones
                                        -a d  set audio device
   -2    downsample 1:2 (22 kHz)        -4    downsample 1:4 (11 kHz)
   -d n  play every n'th frame only     -h n  play every frame n times
   -0    decode channel 0 (left) only   -1    decode channel 1 (right) only
   -m    mix both channels (mono)       -p p  use HTTP proxy p [$HTTP_PROXY]
   -@ f  read filenames/URLs from f
   -z    shuffle play (with wildcards)  -Z    random play
   -u a  HTTP authentication string     -E f  Equalizer, data from file
   -C    enable control keys
See the manpage mpg123(1) or call mpg123 with --longhelp for more information.
sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
sh: line 3: `;/root/Documents/mp3Eclipse/Test_MP3/Test_MP3;exit'
```

I feel that "Commands to execute before application" has no relevance to the code I am trying to run. I can run mpg123 from the terminal and it works properly.

But I want to profile the code and find the execution time for different processes of the application.

Please guide me in this matter.

Comment: By looking at these errors I suspect there is a character that has special meaning in the shell script. [Read up](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) on those and try to escape any of them.

Comment: Because it is unclear that you're running this from Eclipse. (it is also unclear why you want to run this from Eclipse). If you edit your question you should address that and **NOT** add meta-noise about the down votes you get.

Comment: @rene I asked about the down vote because I wanted to know what I needed to do to improve my question.

Comment: Maybe it gets clearer if you link to an [image](http://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Executing_Remote_Applications_with_Eclipse) that shows what you have configured. And you want to run mpg123, right? if so, don't enter anything in "Commands to execute before application". Put your arguments `-/root/Downloads/mpg123-0.59r/sample.mp3` on the second tab (called *arguments*).

Comment: Nobody is required to leave comments or respond to plea's for clarification. Those that do are often met with revenge votes. [Meta.so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) is full of examples with that.